# Unable to play video in Qt5 on snowleopard

Tags: qt, webkit, qt5, quicktime, qtwebkit

When using Qt5 on snowleopard, even with the prebuild 5.1 Qt version, I'm unable to make a video show up in a QWebView, I tried loading the video in a  tag without success.
The Dev tools highlight a 0pixels width x 0px height at the video tag origin.
I tried loading a h264 mp4 file directly into the qwebview, but all it tells me is inside the Qt output console

```
Error loading /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/QuickTime Plugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/QuickTime Plugin:  dlopen(/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/QuickTime Plugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/QuickTime Plugin, 265): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/QuickTime Plugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/QuickTime Plugin: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

And  blank page in the view.
Have no idea where to go from here.
Any idea or suggestion why I'm unable to play videos (even local videos) inside QtWebkit?